# file_exists() is too slow in PHP. Can anyone suggest a faster alternative?

Tags: php, performance, file-exists

When displaying images on our website, we check if the file exists with a call to `file_exists()`. We fall back to a dummy image if the file was missing.

However, profiling has shown that this is the slowest part of generating our pages with `file_exists()` taking up to **1/2 ms** per file. We are only testing 40 or so files, but this still pushes **20ms** onto the page load time.

**Can anyone suggest a way of making this go faster?** Is there a better way of testing if the file is present? If I build a cache of some kind, how should I keep it in sync.

Comment: If the *slowest part* in your code only adds 20ms in total load time, you should go out and treat yourself to a beer, instead of worrying about it so much you're posting a question to SO ;-)

Comment: What file system are you using? - The speed of file_Exists() should mostly depend on the speed of the stat() syscall. How many files are in the directory? (Depending on the file system the number of files has an impact on the stat() speed)

Comment: Show us the code around the function call.

Comment: At 1/2 ms each, you could do 2000 file_exists in a second

Comment: Oh, quoting Wikipedia... *The average length of a blink is 300 to 400 Miliseconds.* Not sure why, but it felt appropriate to share it with you.

Comment: There are a lot of files in the directory (1000's) which is probably impacting the performance more than any other factor. I might look into breaking this up into small batches of files.

Comment: I've actually tried this once, my function took 11 times the execution time of file_exists() so my best bet is to use caching better, or come up with another method.

Comment: You can do an awful lots in 20ms compared to checking of 40 files exist. I don't understand the comments saying that it does not matter.

Comment: what childish comments. 20ms is a lot in some situations, way too much actually.  If this is little for human interaction, it does not mean its fast. For example i am building a templating system, and this delay is killing me, the question is very good

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`file_exists()` should be a very inexpensive operation.  Note too that `file_exists` builds its own cache to help with performance.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I guess I should just accept that the performance is fine and leave it as is. I might go an break up the files into more folders though, as this will probably help things.

Comment: According to the documentation caching will only occur if file_exists() returns true.  So if you happen to check for in-existent files the function will check every time.  You could create a symlink to the dummy image when file_exists() returns false so that subsequent calls will be cached. (this might cause other problems)

Comment: How persistent is the cache? The docs don't say. Is it only for the current request, or does it persist across requests? I would assume it's the former, which doesn't seem like it would help in the OP's scenario.

Answer (score 23):

**Use absolute paths!** Depending on your `include_path` setting PHP checks all(!) these dirs  if you check relative file paths! You might unset `include_path` temporarily before checking the existence.

`realpath()` does the same but I don't know if it is faster.

But file access I/O is always slow. A hard disk access **IS** slower than calculating something in the processor, normally.

Comment: Good tip. I already provide a full path name to the file though (mostly to avoid the unreliable nature of include path settings).

Comment: A thread about this problem and a script to test: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/10394-file_exists-expensive-performance-terms

Comment: I could be wrong, but knowing if a file exists requires a check in the FS index table, so it shouldn't be a real IO operation that expects a file "read" or "write" operation on disk.

Answer (score 23):

The fastest way to check existence of a local file is [**stream_resolve_include_path()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php):

```
if (false !== stream_resolve_include_path($s3url)) { 
  //do stuff 
}
```

Performance results **stream_resolve_include_path()** vs **file_exists()**:

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
stream_resolve  10000           0.051710 sec    +0.00%
file_exists     10000           0.067452 sec    -30.44%
```

In test used absolute paths.
Test source is [here](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/FileExistsVsStreamResolve.php).
PHP version:

> PHP 5.4.23-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: Dec 13 2013 21:53:21)
>  
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 11):

> We fall back to a dummy image if the file was missing

If you're just interested in falling back to this dummy image, you might want to consider letting the client negotiate with the server by means of a redirect (to the dummy image) on file-not-found.

That way you'll just have a little redirection overhead and a not-noticeable delay on the client side. At least you'll get rid of the "expensive" (which it isn't, I know) call to `file_exists`.

Just a thought.

Comment: +1 for clever.  Now I'm curious about what happens if you pass jpg data back with a 404 response.  This is, after all, a 404-type behavior that OP is looking for.

Comment: Should be rendered OK. Basically it's the same behavior for custom 404-pages; ther're rendered as XHTML if served as such. Haven't tested, though.

Answer (score 7):

**Benchmarks with PHP 5.6:**

## Existing File:

```
0.0012969970 : stream_resolve_include_path + include  
0.0013520717 : file_exists + include  
0.0013728141 : @include
```

## Invalid File:

```
0.0000281333 : file_exists + include  
0.0000319480 : stream_resolve_include_path + include  
0.0001471042 : @include
```

## Invalid Folder:

```
0.0000281333 : file_exists + include  
0.0000360012 : stream_resolve_include_path + include  
0.0001239776 : @include
```

**Code:**

```
// microtime(true) is less accurate.
function microtime_as_num($microtime){
  $time = array_sum(explode(' ', $microtime));
  return $time;
}

function test_error_suppression_include ($file) {
  $x = 0;
  $x = @include($file);
  return $x;
}

function test_file_exists_include($file) {
  $x = 0;
  $x = file_exists($file);
  if ($x === true) {
    include $file;
  }
  return $x;
}

function test_stream_resolve_include_path_include($file) {
  $x = 0;
  $x = stream_resolve_include_path($file);
  if ($x !== false) {
    include $file;
  }
  return $x;
}

function run_test($file, $test_name) {
  echo $test_name . ":\n";
  echo str_repeat('=',strlen($test_name) + 1) . "\n";

  $results = array();
  $dec = 10000000000; // digit precision as a multiplier

  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;
  $time_start = 0;
  $time_end = 0;
  $x = -1;
  $time = 0;

  $time_start = microtime();
  $x= test_error_suppression_include($file);
  $time_end = microtime();
  $time = microtime_as_num($time_end) - microtime_as_num($time_start);

  $results[$time*$dec] = '@include';

  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;
  $time_start = 0;
  $time_end = 0;
  $x = -1;
  $time = 0;

  $time_start = microtime();
  $x= test_stream_resolve_include_path_include($file);
  $time_end = microtime();
  $time = microtime_as_num($time_end) - microtime_as_num($time_start);

  $results[$time * $dec] = 'stream_resolve_include_path + include';

  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;
  $time_start = 0;
  $time_end = 0;
  $x = -1;
  $time = 0;

  $time_start = microtime();
  $x= test_file_exists_include($file);
  $time_end = microtime();
  $time = microtime_as_num($time_end) - microtime_as_num($time_start);

  $results[$time * $dec ] = 'file_exists + include';

  ksort($results, SORT_NUMERIC);

  foreach($results as $seconds => $test) {
    echo number_format($seconds/$dec,10) . ' : ' . $test . "\n";
  }
  echo "\n\n";
}

run_test($argv[1],$argv[2]);
```

**Command line Execution:**

```
php test.php '/path/to/existing_but_empty_file.php' 'Existing File'  
php test.php '/path/to/non_existing_file.php' 'Invalid File'  
php test.php '/path/invalid/non_existing_file.php' 'Invalid Folder'
```

Comment: @include  is just **UNACCEPTABLE** and shoud be **NEVER** used, no matter the performance.

Answer (score 4):

Create a hashing routine for sharding the files into multiple sub-directories.

> filename.jpg -> 012345 -> /01/23/45.jpg

Also, you could use mod_rewrite to return your placeholder image for requests to your image directory that 404.

Answer (score 3):

`file_exists()` is automatically cached by PHP. I don't think you'll find a faster function in PHP to check the existence of a file.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316629/is-fileexist-in-php-a-very-expensive-operation).

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly know what you want to do, but you could just [let the client handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images).

Answer (score 2):

If you are only checking for existing `files`, use `is_file()`. 
`file_exists()` checks for a existing file OR directory, so maybe `is_file()` could be a little faster.

Comment: Related: [is_file/file_exists performance and cache](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4099103/500559)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check existence of an image file, a **much faster** way is to use **getimagesize** !

Faster locally and remotely!

```
if(!@GetImageSize($image_path_or_url)) // False means no imagefile
 {
 // Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, I'm going to add an answer here.  For php 5.3.8, is_file() (for an existing file) is an order of magnitude faster.  For a non-existing file, the times are nearly identical.  For PHP 5.1 with eaccelerator, they are a little closer.

PHP 5.3.8 w & w/o APC

```
time ratio (1000 iterations)
Array
(
    [3."is_file('exists')"] => 1.00x    (0.002305269241333)
    [5."is_link('exists')"] => 1.21x    (0.0027914047241211)
    [7."stream_resolve_inclu"(exists)] => 2.79x (0.0064241886138916)
    [1."file_exists('exists')"] => 13.35x   (0.030781030654907)
    [8."stream_resolve_inclu"(nonexists)] => 14.19x (0.032708406448364)
    [4."is_file('nonexists)"] => 14.23x (0.032796382904053)
    [6."is_link('nonexists)"] => 14.33x (0.033039808273315)
    [2."file_exists('nonexists)"] => 14.77x (0.034039735794067)
)
```

PHP 5.1 w/ eaccelerator

```
time ratio (1000x)
Array
(
    [3."is_file('exists')"] => 1.00x    (0.000458002090454)
    [5."is_link('exists')"] => 1.22x    (0.000559568405151)
    [6."is_link('nonexists')"] => 3.27x (0.00149989128113)
    [4."is_file('nonexists')"] => 3.36x (0.00153875350952)
    [2."file_exists('nonexists')"] => 3.92x (0.00179600715637)
    [1."file_exists('exists"] => 4.22x  (0.00193166732788)
)
```

There are a couple of caveats.
1) Not all "files" are files, is_file() tests for *regular* files, not symlinks.  So on a *nix system, you can't get away with just is_file() unless you are *sure* that you are only dealing with regular files.  For uploads, etc, this may be a fair assumption, or if the server is Windows based, which does not actually have symlinks.  Otherwise, you'll have to test `is_file($file) || is_link($file)`.

2) Performance definitely degrades for all methods if the file is missing and becomes roughly equal.

3) Biggest caveat.  All the methods cache the file statistics to speed lookup, so if the file is changing regularly or quickly, deleted, reappears, deletes, then `clearstatcache();` has to be run to insure that the correct file existence information is in the cache.  So I tested those.  I left out all the filenames and such.  The important thing is that almost all the times converge, except stream_resolve_include, which is 4x as fast.  Again, this server has eaccelerator on it, so YMMV.

```
time ratio (1000x)
Array
(
    [7."stream_resolve_inclu...;clearstatcache();"] => 1.00x    (0.0066831111907959)
    [1."file_exists(...........;clearstatcache();"] => 4.39x    (0.029333114624023)
    [3."is_file(................;clearstatcache();] => 4.55x    (0.030423402786255)
    [5."is_link(................;clearstatcache();] => 4.61x    (0.030798196792603)
    [4."is_file(................;clearstatcache();] => 4.89x    (0.032709360122681)
    [8."stream_resolve_inclu...;clearstatcache();"] => 4.90x    (0.032740354537964)
    [2."file_exists(...........;clearstatcache();"] => 4.92x    (0.032855272293091)
    [6."is_link(...............;clearstatcache();"] => 5.11x    (0.034154653549194)
)
```

Basically, the idea is, if you're 100% sure that it is a file, not a symlink or a directory, and in all probability, it will exist, then use `is_file()`.  You'll see a definite gain.  If the file could be a file or a symlink at any moment, then the failed is_file() 14x + is_link() 14x  (`is_file() || is_link()`), and will end up being 2x slower overall.  If the file's existence changes A LOT, then use stream_resolve_include_path().

So it depends on your usage scenario.

Comment: Now, this is old *answer*

Answer (score 2):

In 2021, 12 years later since the question was asked I have the same use case. I was not satisfied with the answers here and made an experiment. I check in a loop if one of around 40 images exists among the images in a folder with `file_exist`.

Here are the figures (PHP 7.4) in milliseconds:

- on local dev machine (Win10, WAMP, Samsung SSD, Intel 3.4GHz): roughly 0.1 (1/10) millisecond per image, roughly 1000 images in the folder;
- on server (pretty basic cheap one, VPS 1 Intel Xeon, RAM 2GB, SSD, Ubuntu, LAMP): roughly 0.01 (1/100) millisecond per image, 14,000 images in the folder;

The server is 10 times faster than the dev machine, and quite indistinguishable from overall UX performance POV where 30-50 ms is somewhat first noticeable threshold.

On server checking the array of 40 images I spend 0.4 ms to check if any of them not-existent. BTW no difference in performance whether some of the images exist or not.

So this should be of no question whether to check with `file_exist` or not because of disk performance. Check if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Are they all in the same directory? If so it *may* be worth getting the list of files and storing them in a hash and comparing against that rather than all the file_exists lookups.

Comment: I'm assuming this hash would be stored in APC somewhere... or some other sort of shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

What about `glob()`? But I'm not sure if it's fast.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: glob() is a dinosaur compared to file_exists()! I don't think it will help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I find 1/2ms per call very, very affordable. I don't think there are much faster alternatives around, as the file functions are very close to the lower layers that handle file operations.

You could however write a wrapper to file_exists() that caches results into a memcache or similar facility. That should reduce the time to next to nothing in everyday use.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cronjob to periodically create a list of images and store them in DB/file/BDB/...

Every half an hour should be fine, but be sure to create an interface to reset cache in case of file addition/delete.

And then, it's also easy to run find . -mmin -30 -print0  on the shell and add new files.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a file to a folder, if the upload was successfully, you can store the path to a DB Table.

Then you will just have to make a query to the database in order to find the path of the requested file.

Comment: Databases are stored on disk too*, are you sure it would be faster?
* usually

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page looking for a solution, and it seems fopen may do the trick. If you use this code, you might want to disable error logging for the files that are not found.

```
<?php
for ($n=1;$n<100;$n++){
clearstatcache();
$h=@fopen("files.php","r");
if ($h){
echo "F";
fclose($h);
}else{
echo "N";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to keep the image url in the database and then put it in a session variable especially when you have authentication. These way you dont have to be checking each time a page reloads

Answer (score -1):

I'm not even sure if this will be any faster but it appears as though you would still like to benchmark soooo:

**Build a cache of a large array of all image paths.**

```
$array = array('/path/to/file.jpg' => true, '/path/to/file2.gif' => true);
```

Update the cache **hourly** or **daily** depending on your requirements.  You would do this utilizing **cron** to run a PHP script which will recursively go through the files directory to generate the array of paths.

When you wish to check if a file exists, load your cached array and do a simply **isset()** check for a fast array index lookup:

```
if (isset($myCachedArray[$imgpath])) {
    // handle display
}
```

There will still be overhead from loading the cache but it will hopefully be small enough to stay in memory.  If you have multiple images you are checking for on a page you will probably notice more significant gains as you can load the cache on page load.