# will file_exist() php function cause high server load?

Tags: php, file-exists

i am trying to check if user uploaded his or her avatar image and i use file_exist() php function to check if the user avatar image exist or not

will this cause any server load problem with massive traffic websites ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it will not, here is the documentation for [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). It also caches the results, so that further improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same question has been [asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316629/is-fileexist-in-php-a-very-expensive-operation).

The short answer was: **no**.

Comment: you are referring to the same question ! please make sure the next time

Comment: Sorry, I probably mixed them in my copy-paste buffer.